# Java program to read objects from a .ser file located in a server

Tags: java, file, http, object

My idea is that I want to read an object from a serialized file located in a server. How to do that?

I can only read .txt file using the following code :

```
   void getInfo() {
    try {
        URL url;
        URLConnection urlConn;
        DataInputStream dis;

        url = new URL("http://localhost/Test.txt");

        // Note:  a more portable URL: 
        //url = new URL(getCodeBase().toString() + "/ToDoList/ToDoList.txt");

        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);

        dis = new DataInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());

        String s;
        while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        dis.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        System.out.println("Error!!!");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error!!!");
    }
   }
```

Comment: readLine() is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29)

Comment: What message do you get if you use another URL ? Exist the URL on the server ?

Comment: No, this code works fine. The problem is this works only for primitive data types and not class objects. What changes should I make to read a class object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with this method

```
  public Object deserialize(InputStream is) {
    ObjectInputStream in;
    Object obj;
    try {
      in = new ObjectInputStream(is);
      obj = in.readObject();
      in.close();
      return obj;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }
```

feed it with `urlConn.getInputStream()` and you'll get the `Object`. `DataInputStream` is not fit to read serialized objets that are done with `ObjectOutputStream`. Use `ObjectInputStream` respectively.

To write an object to the file there's another method

```
  public void serialize(Object obj, String fileName) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    try {
      fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
      out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
      out.writeObject(obj);
      out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Got It. One more question : Can we write objects in the same way?

Comment: @AntonioKumar that needs another method that writes to the `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: @AntonioKumar localhost is not the filename, but the file name is a parameter to the method

Comment: If I give filename as "http://localhost/Temp.ser". It is giving a file not found exception.

Comment: you should write the file by the absolute path name not the url